# How can I determine the build/version of Linux kernel 'uImage'?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to track down a kernel binary; ***is there a way to determine the version (build string) of a Linux 'uImage' binary?***

Running

```
strings uImage
```

piped into various trailing `grep` statements leads me to think I'm dealing with a compressed image...

Comment: As per this answer https://superuser.com/a/1234270/439040 if you are in fact dealing with a compressed kernel image bzImage file (people in both the question and answers do seem to be dealing with both formats already) then `file -bL [bzImage]`, e.g. `file -bL /boot/vmlinuz`, will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized, the kernels I have immediate access to *do* have the version string stored uncompressed amongst the headers. `strings uImage | grep 2.6` ought to be good enough for any 2.6 kernel which covers pretty much everything in the last 5+ years).

(original answer follows)

---

It's theoretically possible, but not entirely trivial.

Modern Linux kernel versions use a format called bzImage (for x86/x86_64, YMMV on other platforms). It actually consists of an ELF header and some other minutia (like a bit of decompression code) followed by, yes, a compressed image of the actual kernel.

Traditionally, the compression algorithm was zlib (contrary to popular misconception, 'bzImage' did *not* stand for "bzipped image", but for "big zImage" -- the original zImage format not being able to handle large kernels), though versions after 2.6.30 also support bzip2 and LZMA.

What you'll probably have to do is determine exactly where the compressed data starts (sorry, can't help you there, but trial and error might work), and write a bit of code to run it through the library for whichever compression algorithm is in use.

Answer (score 8):

According to kernel's format specification, here's C code:

### **kver.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (argc > 1){
        FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        short offset = 0;
        char str[128];
        if(f){
            fseek(f, 0x20E, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&offset, 2, 1, f);
            fseek(f, offset + 0x200, SEEK_SET);
            fread(str, 128, 1, f);
            str[127] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", str);
            fclose(f);
            return 0;
        }else {
            return 2;
        }
    } else {
        printf("use: kver [kernel image file]\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

compile and run:

```
gcc -o kver kver.c
./kver /boot/vmlinux-something
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately though, it doesn't work for me for a 4.19 kernel. Has the spec changed recently? `kver` against that vmlinux just outputs `\n`, but no contents.

Comment: This is a very useful code sample, however worth noting that (AFAICT) it applies to compressed vmlinuz rather than extracted vmlinux. (And I just get `\n` when running it against vmlinux too.)

Answer (score 8):

To find out what version of Linux is compiled, use the `strings` utility on the uncompressed vmlinux image.

For example:

`strings linux-src/build/build-generic/vmlinux|grep "Linux version"`

Sample output:

`Linux version 3.2.0-56-generic (root@puerto-cayo) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #86 SMP Fri Nov 1 10:24:18 EDT 2013 (Ubuntu 3.2.0-56.86-generic 3.2.51)`

Comment: How does this get an upvote, when Nicholas Knight answered the same thing 2-1/2 years ago?

Comment: This answer requires no thinking hence it is better. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try `file uImage`.  It might identify the file format if it is a commonly known compression format.  Other than that, the `strings` utility is probably the best one for this task.

Answer (score 2):

This will output the kernel version and the localversion string (if any was set at build time) on a bzimage:

```
 strings bzimage |grep -E "^[1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" |awk '{print $1}' |head -1
```

I've tested it on kernel versions 3 and 4 ... but it should also work on previous versions too.

```
strings vmlinuz |grep -E "^[1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" |awk '{print $1}' |head -1
4.4.5
strings vmlinux |grep -E "^[1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" |awk '{print $1}' |head -1
3.2.45-smp
```

If you have uImage you will haveto remove the "^" or it will not match anything

```
strings uImage |grep -E "[1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" |head -1
Linux-3.0.76
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a kernel for x86, it has the version in the header. See [Documentation/x86/boot.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/Documentation/x86/boot.txt) (look at the `kernel_version` field).

I do not know if the same is true for other architectures (that header is x86-specific).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure however you might try `uname -a` may be this is what you want.

Comment: That gives the build string of the host environment; I'm looking to see inside a kernel image I've got stored as a `uImage` file.  Thanks for responding though.