# How to identify the kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How can I know which version of the kernel I'm using?

uname - a
Unknown GLBMPL360JK 999.999.999 x86_64 GNU / Linux

cat /proceso/cpuinfo
0
how could I know the kernel version thanks
link of the operating system : https://sourceforge.net/projects/sistemas-operativos/

Comment: Hi vlan,  Your question is a better fit for [https://unix.stackexchange.com/](Unix & Linux) or [https://serverfault.com/](ServerFault)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a macro definition to check the Linux kernel version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16721346/608639), [Read linux kernel version using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2987592/608639), [Getting kernel version from linux kernel module at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030758/608639), [How can I determine the build/version of Linux kernel 'uImage'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3180029/608639)

Answer (score 2):

1. Have a look at /proc/version file this will kernel version details
2. /usr/include/linux/version.h file will have version code.
   Decode the version then you can get the current kernel version.